# Multiply column of a matrix with row of another matrix in Julia

Tags: matrix, vector, julia, multiplication

Let

```
A = rand(3,3);B = rand(3,3)
```

I can multiply first column of `A : A[:,1]` with third row of matrix `B : B[3,:]`
by the command:

```
reshape(A[:,1],3,1)*reshape(B[3,:],1,3)
```

to make a 3x3 matrix.

The direct computation

```
A[:,1]*B[3,:]
```

is giving the error:

```
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching *(::Vector{Float64}, ::Vector{Float64})
Closest candidates are:
  *(::Any, ::Any, ::Any, ::Any...) at operators.jl:560
  *(::StridedMatrix{T}, ::StridedVector{S}) where {T<:Union{Float32, Float64, ComplexF32, ComplexF64}, S<:Real} at C:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.6\LinearAlgebra\src\matmul.jl:44
  *(::StridedVecOrMat{T} where T, ::LinearAlgebra.Adjoint{var"#s832", var"#s831"} where {var"#s832", var"#s831"<:LinearAlgebra.LQPackedQ}) at C:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.6\LinearAlgebra\src\lq.jl:254
  ...
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope
   @ REPL[2]:1
```

Is there any other short/clear method to do this operation?

Answer : `A[:, 1:1] * B[3:3, :]` and `A[:, 1] * B[3, :]'` from @phipsgabler's reply. Or  `view(A, :, 1)*view(B, 3, :)'` , `@views A[:, 1] * B[3, :]'` without copying rows or columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`A[:, 1]` and `B[3, :]` are both `Vector`s -- rank 1 -- so it is not automatically clear what you want here.  The more likely option would be the inner product:

```
julia> dot(A[:, 1], B[3, :])
0.8875027511646011

julia> A[:, 1]' * B[3, :]
0.8875027511646011
```

But it seems you want the outer product:

```
julia> reshape(A[:,1],3,1)*reshape(B[3,:],1,3)
3×3 Matrix{Float64}:
 0.689437  0.246968   0.190616
 0.400674  0.143528   0.110778
 0.197257  0.0706608  0.0545377

julia> A[:, 1:1] * B[3:3, :]
3×3 Matrix{Float64}:
 0.689437  0.246968   0.190616
 0.400674  0.143528   0.110778
 0.197257  0.0706608  0.0545377

julia> A[:, 1] * B[3, :]'
3×3 Matrix{Float64}:
 0.689437  0.246968   0.190616
 0.400674  0.143528   0.110778
 0.197257  0.0706608  0.0545377
```

To explain: by using a range, `1:1`, instead of an index, the result will still be a matrix (just like your `reshape` approach):

```
julia> B[3:3, :]
1×3 Matrix{Float64}:
 0.938292  0.336112  0.259419
```

That way the `*` is well defined as the matrix product between a one-column matrix and a one-row matrix.

The same holds if you transpose one of the vectors:

```
julia> B[3, :]'
1×3 adjoint(::Vector{Float64}) with eltype Float64:
 0.938292  0.336112  0.259419
```

The product between a vector and a covector is also well-defined.

The last option is to use [`kron`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/LinearAlgebra/#Base.kron); this however vectorizes the result, and you have to reshape the output:

```
julia> reshape(kron(A[:, 1], B[3, :]), 3, 3)
3×3 Matrix{Float64}:
 0.689437  0.400674  0.197257
 0.246968  0.143528  0.0706608
 0.190616  0.110778  0.0545377
```

Comment: A[:, 1:1] * B[3:3, :] is the thing I wanted.

Comment: But note that this copies the slices. Ideally, you should use a view for things like this.

Comment: Can you include that also : based on view.

Comment: It's just a matter of wrapping the indexing part, see [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/performance-tips/#man-performance-views).

Comment: Is it view(A, :, 1)*view(B, 3, :)' what you mean? @phipsgabler

Comment: That would work. As would `@views A[:, 1] * B[3, :]'`.